# Understanding synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, scjp

Given this code:

```
public class Messager implements Runnable {            

  public static void main(String[] args) {   
      new Thread(new Messager("Wallace")).start();    
      new Thread(new Messager("Gromit")).start();             
  }             
  private String name;                 
  public Messager(String name) { this.name = name; }             
  public void run() {    
      message(1); message(2);    
  }           
  private synchronized void message(int n) {    
    System.out.print(name + "-" + n + " ");    
  }    
}
```

I understand that the `synchronized` keyword makes the thread dependent on the object's lock. Questions:

a) Is the lock released as soon as the method marked as `synchronized` finishes? Or as soon as the thread's `run()` method finishes
b) Can I ensure that any one of the threads will print its name and `1 2` before the other?

Comment: You are actually locking on two different instances there, so the `sycnhronized` wont do anything. (Explicitly using the `synchronized` block rather than modifier makes things clearer. Better use a separate lock object.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A. Yes. It's released as soon as the `synchronized` function finishes.
B. Yes. You can, but if you wanted to do so, why would you write multithreaded code in the first place? `synchronized` guarantees atomicity, not anything regarding the order, but you can enforce order by waiting for a flag to change. Anyway, what you are trying to enforce is **sequentiality**. You get this for free in single-threaded environments :)

Comment: Oh, I'm just asking a "what if" question. I'm studying for the scjp. Thanks.

Comment: dmindreader, please add new tag scjp to future scjp questions, thanks.